# Tracing what blocks go through L2ARC in ZFS on Solaris using dtrace

Tags: solaris, zfs, dtrace, zfs-l2arc

My colleague and myself are trying to trace the reads/writes to the L2ARC in OpenZFS. We want the block offsets, IO type (read/write) and the device-ids of the requests. Note that we don't want the offset in the L2ARC device but we want the offset/device-id from the original storage device in order to model what storage blocks go through the L2ARC cache.

Going through the OpenZFS source (github.com/openzfs/openzfs/blob/master/usr/src/uts/common/fs/zfs/arc.c) and using Brendan's dtrace tutorial (dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2012/01/09/activity-of-the-zfs-arc) has been useful.

We believe the `arc_buf_hdr_t` struct contains the information we are looking for. More precisely the `dva_t b_dva;` field contains the offset and the device id of the underlying storage device and we can access an instance of `arc_buf_hdr_t` (variable name is `hdr`) via the `arc__miss` dtrace probe event. This gives us the L2ARC reads but the writes are harder to get. Namely the `l2arc__write` dtrace probe event doesn't have access to this `hdr`, it [should](https://github.com/openzfs/openzfs/blob/master/usr/src/uts/common/fs/zfs/arc.c#L6845) be in the [`io_private`](https://github.com/openzfs/openzfs/blob/master/usr/src/uts/common/fs/zfs/zio.c#L575) field on the `zio_t` that is passed into `l2arc__write` but it is always NULL in our testbed which doesn't make sense to us.

Is there some clean way to get the DVA on the `l2arc__write` dtrace probe event?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that we were using a 2015 version of OpenIndiana and in that particular version the `hdr` was not set on `zio->io_private`.

[This commit from 2016](https://github.com/openzfs/openzfs/commit/7fc10f0415b04cb8090712dad5535069ff20f6a9) resolves the issue and by using a 2016 version of OpenIndiana we are able to get access to `hdr` via `zio->io_private`.